# how to get assembly code from .lua or from byte code?

Tags: assembly, lua, compilation, luac

i'd like to study assembly code from lua code.
for the moment , i can get byte code with command :

```
luac filename.lua
```

I work on linux platform, how to compile it ?
Should i compile it in order to study his assembly code ?
how to disassemble it  ?

Comment: Do any LUA interpreters even JIT compile to native machine code at all?  If they just interpret, then the only code running on the CPU is the ahead-of-time-compiled interpreter itself.  (Which you can of course disasemble and/or profile with `perf record`, or just look at its source code).

Comment: You can view list of bytecode instructions: `luac -l -l -p filename.lua` or `luac -l -l -p filename.luac`  There is [luac file viewer](https://lua-bytecode.github.io/) which shows a short description for every bytecode instruction.

Comment: There is a [Lua compiler](http://www.chunkbake.luaforge.net/) to convert sequence of bytecode instructions to luac file.

Comment: You can view the bytecode instructions through this website too: https://www.luac.nl/, with short descriptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stock Lua does not compile the bytecode into assembly code, it has a bytecode execution engine, the Lua virtual machine.  So